# Maps of generic lists not converting nicely

Tags: java, generics

Rather than attempt this in words, I'll just give an example:

I have an Animal class, as well as a Dog,Fish,Cat, etc. which extend Animal.

I have three different methods, which return `Map<String,List<Dog>>, Map<String,List<Fish>>, Map<String,List<Cat>>`. We'll call these getDogMap, getCatMap, and getFishMap.

I am writing a generic method which, depending on various parameters, calls one of these methods. Here is what I expected to be allowed to do:

```
public void <A extends Animal> doSomething(){

    Map<String,List<A>> someMap;

    if(someCondition){
        someMap = getDogMap();
    }else if(anotherCondition){
        someMap = getFishMap();
    }else{
        someMap = getCatMap():
    }
}
```

Or at least, that with casting ala `someMap = (Map<String,List<Dog>>) getDogMap();`

However, this does not work. Eclipse tells me `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List<Dog>> to Map<String,List<A>>"` If I try to force the cast, it tells me `"Cannot cast from Map<STring,List<Dog>> to Map<String,List<A>>"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Map<String,List<A extends Animal>> someMap; ` ?

Comment: @ant Except that won't compile, you can't define a type variable nor an extra bound on a type variable in a declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public void <A extends Animal>` doesn't mean "`A` is any type that extends `Animal`", it means "`A` is a specific one of the types that extends `Animal`". You need to use the following declarations:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Animal>>  someMap;
    // ...
}
```

The construct `? extends Animal` is how you express "any type that extends `Animal`".

The reason you have to use that declaration is that, counter-intuitively, the way subtype relationships between generic types work isn't exactly consistent with how they work between regular types. For instance, `List<Dog>` is a subtype of `Collection<Dog>`. It is **not** a subtype of `List<Animal>`, or `Collection<Animal>` etc. The reason why this isn't allowed is called *heap pollution*, also explained in [Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ050). `List<Dog>` is, however, a subtype of `List<? extends Animal>`. A variable of type `List<? extends Animal>` may have assigned a `List<Dog>`, or a `List<Cat>`, or a `List<Animal>`. The important part is that the compiler doesn't know which of these it is, just that it is one of them.

Just like `List<Dog>` is **not** a subtype of `List<Animal>`, analogously it holds that `Map<String, List<Dog>>` is **not** a subtype of `Map<String, List<? extends Animal>>`.

The best way to demonstrate why generics work this way is proof by contradiction; that is, showing examples of (broken) code that would lead to errors were generics to work "intuitively". So, if `List<Dog>` were a subtype of `List<Animal>`, the following code would be valid:

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
List<Animal> animals = dogs; // unsafe cast

// this operation violates type safety
animals.add(new Cat());

// would assign a Cat to a variable of type Dog without a compile error!
Dog dog = animals.get(0);
```

Similarly, for your `Map`:

```
Map<String, List<Dog>> dogses = new HashMap<String, List<Dog>>();
Map<String, List<? extends Animal>> animalses = dogses; // unsafe cast

List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList();
cats.put(new Cat());
animalses.put("cats", cats);

List<Dog> dogs = dogses.get("cats");
Dog dog = dogs.get(0); // uh-oh
```

Comment: You're right, but that is the functionality I want. This is a Map from a String to a list of ONE type of Animal. And these three methods return that. (Also, to put it aside, using <? extends Animal> gives the same error). Also, I think you are misunderstanding the difference between the usage of ? and A. In this situation, they are exactly the same. They only differ if, for example, I pass in a Class<A>, which allows me to explicitly set A.

Comment: Your three methods all return *different* subtypes of `Animal`. Therefore, a single variable that can hold the return values of any of these methods must be able to hold any subtype of `Animal`.

Comment: A could be any of those types. This is not an issue.

Comment: "A could be any of those types" - except your original code isn't expressing this constraint correctly. (I also fixed my answer to one that actually compiles now.)

Comment: A rule of thumb: if your method has a type parameter that's used neither in the argument types, or in the return type, you're probably going about things the wrong way. Method type parameters are useful *only* to express constraints on / between argument / retval types, they don't meaningfully affect local variables in the method body.

Comment: Could you explain that edit to me? I can't exactly grasp the purpose of ? extends List<? extends Animal>. How is something extending list? Especially given the discussion below, regarding the fact that List<Dog> is not a child of List<Animal>

Comment: @Seth The short version is "because that's how subtype relationships work with generics and you need both the `extends` to make the compiler shut up". For the long version I'll defer to [this entry in Angelika Langer's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ006A) as well as the rest of it. It's pretty much the definitive resource when it comes to Java's generics. (I'll add an explanation in terms of your example in when it's not the middle of the night.)

Comment: @Seth I've added a longer explanation on why you have to use the two `? extends X` constructs, hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies in the way generic types work.

In Java, you would expect that `Number` is a superclass of `Integer` (and you would be right). You would also expect that `Number[]` is a superclass of `Integer[]`. You would also be right. However, you cannot say that `List<Number>` is a superclass of `List<Integer>`. This violates type safety.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numList = intList; // the system stops you here
numList.add(Math.PI); // so that you don't do this
```

In you case, you have a type `Animal` and its subtypes `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Fish`. Extend this logic to your animals, and you see why you are having trouble casting `List<Dog>` to `List<A>`.

Now, you can use the `addAll(Collection)` method defined in the `List` interface.

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
animals.addAll(dogs);
```

Comment: YES. Thank you for actually understanding my problem. Now - do you have a solution?!? Or do I have to write three helper methods to typecast each element in each list.

Comment: Can you simply declare someMap to be of type `Map<String,List<Animal>>`?

Comment: That won't work for the same reason you described above. I cannot cast from List<Dog> to List<Animal>.

Comment: Wow. Don't know what I was thinking there. Give me a second, I'll think of something...

Comment: One answer is `Map<String, ?> someMap` or `Map<String, List<?>> someMap` or `Map<String, List<? extends Animal>> someMap` ... but these force you to use typecasts when reading from the lists.
`

Comment: @StephenC And rightly so. The compiler can't possibly verify which subtype of `List<? extends Animal>` is stored under which map key, so you necessarily have to cast. There are some constraints generics simply can't express.